# Clicking Google reCAPTCHA checkmark does nothing on IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, recaptcha, message-channel

Google reCAPTCHA is not working on IE9 (compatibility view is disabled). It loads correctly but the checkmark is not clickable. After some seconds, the checkmark disappears and it shows:

> Please upgrade to a supported browser to get a reCAPTCHA challenge.
>
> Alternatively if you think you are getting this page in error, please
>   check your internet connection and reload.

It also throws the following error:

`'MessageChannel' is undefined`

It looks like Google reCAPTCHA is no longer supported on IE<10 since the Channel Messaging API is not supported.

Is there any way to make it work on IE9? Has anyone been able or at least tried to port the Channel Messaging API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed any windows security updates?

Did you change any group policy like 'Turn off Data URI support'?

If yes, then try to enable this policy or for a testing purpose try to remove that security update may solve the issue.

Also try to make a test with other browsers and check whether you have same issue with those browsers or it works correctly.

It can help us to narrow down the issue.

You can let us know about your testing results. We will try to provide you further suggestions.

Regards
Deepak

Comment: Hi Deepak, thanks for your comment. The issue only happens on IE9 (and probably in older versions of IE but I don't need to support them). I haven't installed any Windows Security Updates or changed any policies. The issue seems to be related to the use of the Channel Messaging API which is not supported by IE9.